# Y axis starting point

Tags: objective-c, bemsimplelinegraph

Is it possible to set the 0 point of the graph to be exactly above the X axis labels when autoScaleYAxis is set to YES?

I implemented the baseValueForYAxisOnLineGraph but this only tells it from what point the y labels should start.

Answer (score 1):

This will make the 0 value to be exactly over the x labels.

```
- (CGFloat) staticPaddingForLineGraph:(BEMSimpleLineGraphView * __nonnull)graph{
    return 28;
}
```

If you have bezier curves set to yes then the line that delimits the top and bottom part of the graph sometime goes over to X axis labels.

Comment: This should be fixed with the 4.1 of [BEMSimpleLineGraph](https://github.com/Boris-Em/BEMSimpleLineGraph)